# How to set up a simple modeling problem

Tags: regression, machine-learning, modeling, k-nearest-neighbour

I am having trouble setting up a problem and was looking for help. I will present a simplified version:

The dataset has 10,000 customers. The target variable, Y, has two states: 1 if the product is owned, 0 if it is not. There are 1,000 customers who own (Y=1) and 9,000 who do not (Y=0). There are also a set of predictors (X).

The questions is, what is the best way to predict which of the 9,000 who do not own the product are most like the 1,000 who do and therefore may be most likely to purchase it?

I would like to do some form of logisitic regression because it is simple and interpretable, however I can't figure out how to set it up. Say I use the whole data set and regress Y against X. Then who out of the Y=0 people should be targeted? Those with the highest probability of being Y=1 but are actually not?

My best guess now is a nearest neighbor search, where I take an average of the Y=1 customers and rank the Y=0 customers based on distance to that vector. But I feel as if there is a better way.

I'm sure I am missing something obvious here. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: To me the essence of your first approach, straight logistic regression, seems more reasonable than the second one, nearest neighbor. Consider that your second approach uses no information about relative importance of the different predictors (or even their units, i.e. you could change the results by changing the measurement units!). A Gaussian Mixture model could perhaps be a more reasonable version the second approach.